# Put most nonUI code in background thread?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

Is it a good idea to put most of the non UI code in background thread to improve the UI experience? Especially in ViewDidLoad? Below is my viewDidLoad code and I have made comment about where I think I could put background thread

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Put this in background thread?
    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient()

    // Put this in background thread?
    postDescriptionTxtView.delegate = self

    // Put this in background thread?
    let hideTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myVC.hideKeyboard))
    hideTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(hideTap)

    whiteViewForEditImgBtn.layer.cornerRadius = whiteViewForEditImgBtn.frame.width / 2
    whiteViewForEditImgBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true

    selectedImageView.image = imageFromPreviousVC

    contentView.backgroundColor = COLOR_BACKGROUND_POSTVC
    postBtn.backgroundColor = COLOR_BUTTON
    topView.backgroundColor = COLOR_NAVIGATION_BARTINT
}
```

Comment: I understand your logic but I think this might be going a bit too far! I think Apple's guidelines are that if you have a process that could have a noticeable impact on UI update performance (somewhat subjective but I think we all have an idea of what that means), you should think about using background queues. Otherwise you might be adding in a whole load of complication into your app for little marginal benefit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving an operation to background thread improves user experience only in situations when the operation delays rendering of the screen. This happens in two situations - when the operation is CPU-intensive, and when the operation goes into a wait state, e.g. to wait for a network request to complete.

We can estimate how CPU-intensive an operation needs to be in order for us to consider moving it off the UI thread. Assuming 1.3 GHz core speed and FPS rate of 60, we have about 2,000,000 CPU cycles between rendering two consecutive frames. If your operation needs significantly more cycles than that, you may consider moving it to a separate thread.

In contrast, operations with network waits could take unpredictably long to complete, so one should avoid running them on the UI thread.

Your example would probably fit in about 100 instructions, counting the instructions executed as part of the methods that it calls. Since your example does not make network calls either, moving it to a background thread would introduce needless complexity, without providing any benefit in return.